# Microsoft Appsource Onboarding #appsource

Tags: appsource

I'm new to this site so apologies if formatting or style of question is not as you would expect.We are an ISV in the process of getting a product listed on Microsoft AppSource.

We have a web application that is hosted in Azure and meets the requirements for using Azure Authentication.

Our Web application appears to be functioning normally up to the point when the AppSource team authenticate - which they do successfully - at this point they get a webpage error as follows which says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (see attachment)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPWI6.png)

Can anyone suggest how to get around this ? It seems like it could be simple a proxy issue at the Microsoft end, although its not completely clear to us if this is the case. Interestingly our product acts as a proxy / reverse proxy encryption gateway.

Comment: Please add more information about how you are requesting the token such as code snippets. Are you using adal.js or msal.js? Also, because you published your web app in Azure, is the Authentication options in Azure disabled? (in general if you are using adal.js or msal.js, you do not need to enable authentication in Azure Web App settings).

Comment: Also, take a look at this [FAQ for adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQ)